# jest regex from npm script

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, jestjs

I want to execute 2 different test environments,
one for `integration tests` and the second is for `unit tests`.

The folders structure is something like this:

```
__tests__/ut/p/a/t/h/file.test.ts
__tests__/it/p/a/t/h/file.test.ts
```

I have come up with these regex:

`(__tests__/ut/.*\.test)\.(tsx?|ts?)$`
`(__tests__/it/.*\.test)\.(tsx?|ts?)$`

My scripts looks like this:

```
"test:ut": "jest \"(__tests__/ut/.*\\.test)\\.(tsx?|ts?)$\"",
"test:it": "jest \"(__tests__/it/.*\\.test)\\.(tsx?|ts?)$\"",
```

But when I run `yarn test:ut` I get:

```
yarn run v1.3.2
$ jest "(__tests__/ut/.*\.test)\.(tsx?|ts?)$"
No tests found
In /home/dev/sample
  20 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x) - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 20 matches
Pattern: (__tests__/ut/.*\.test)\.(tsx?|ts?)$ - 0 matches
Done in 0.49s.
```

Though, if I use the same pattern in a json configuration file it works.
I guess it something with how I execute the `jest`.
How can I fix it?

**EDIT**

Executing this:

`"test:ut": "jest -c jest.json \"(__tests__\\/ut\\/.*\\.test)\\.(tsx?|ts?)$\"",`

result with the `no tests found`.
But if I put the regex inside the configuration file, it does work:

```
{
  "testRegex": "(__tests__\\/ut\\/.*\\.test)\\.(tsx?|ts?)$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "json",
    "jsx"
  ]
}
```

Executing it as `npm script` I just comment out the `testRegex` from the config file.

Comment: Without having much knowledge of jest itself, why is `testMatch` matching ".js" or ".jsx" files, but your regex is matching TypeScript? If the regex is only matching against what the initial testMatch is collecting then you won't have any of your ts files in the collection to match against. Just a guess.

Comment: A second and different comment, are your tests in "/home/dev/sample/__tests__/..." From the output one could assume that if there are "20 files checked" and "20 matches" for the testPathIgnorePatterns then it something else could be wrong (though, again, just a guess. It's possible the 20 ignore directory matches are separate from the 20 files checked).

Comment: I have no idea why is it searching `js` files... I've added something to the question

Answer (score 2):

I came here with a similar problem and what finally worked for me is the Jest CLI option [--testPathIgnorePatterns](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testpathignorepatterns-array-string). So for your problem, where you only have two test locations, I would exclude the `/ut/` folder when doing the `it` tests, and vice versa:

```
"test:ut": "jest --testPathIgnorePatterns \"/(it)/\"",
"test:it": "jest --testPathIgnorePatterns \"/(ut)/\"",
```

Also, if it helps, I did not use `testRegex` in my Jest config, but rather:

```
"testMatch": [
  "/__tests__/.*\\.(ts|tsx|js)",
  "**/?(*.)(spec|test).ts?(x)"
],
```